# SSL error on woocommerce callback in wc auth

Tags: wordpress, authentication, ssl, woocommerce

I am using the wc-auth login of woocommerce.
the one like this https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/08/07/api-settings-and-the-api-authentication-endpoint-in-2-4/

now both sites have SSL installed properly I checked them on online sslcheckers.

But on the wc-auth way of logging in, I get this error:

```
Error: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.my-domain.com'
```

I have checked the alternative name and it has *.mydomain.com in it.

Hence i am unable to understand what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if both site SSL checkout then you should not be having any issues. For troubleshooting purposes try using a callback_url without the www subdomain.

Comment: I tried that too, still the same error without the www .